# Partial derivative of function evaluated at fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, systems-of-equations

Consider a function $f\left(x,y,\Lambda\right)$ where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}<0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}>0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \Lambda}>0$. We know that $x>0$, $y>0$ and $f(x,y)\in\left[0,1\right]$. Moreover, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Further, let $x^\star$ and $y^\star$ be the solutions of the system:

$$x^\star = \arg\max_x f\left(x,y^\star,\Lambda\right) \times x$$
$$y^\star = \arg\max_y (1-f\left(x^\star,y,\Lambda\right)) \times y$$

I need to show that: $\frac{d f\left(x^\star, y^\star, \Lambda\right)}{d \Lambda}>0$.

Comment: Writing $\times$ at this level of mathematics is not helpful. So $x^\star$ and $y^\star$ are functions of $\Lambda$ and you want $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda)\frac{dx^\star}{d\Lambda} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda)\frac{dy^\star}{d\Lambda} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial\Lambda}(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda)?$$

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: A couple of us in the chatroom have worked on this for several hours and gotten nowhere. You may need second derivative information on $f$ or just need to know some facts that we are not clever enough to know.

Comment: I got to the point where $f\left(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda\right)=\frac{x^\star}{x^\star+y^\star}$. From there I tried to take the derivative of this object directly and compare to the expression you had but to no avail. One other assumption is that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$. Any notes or leads are helpful..

Comment: No, it's mixed partials $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\Lambda\partial x}$ that are showing up. I didn't get your equation, but the asymmetry surprises me.

Comment: I showed that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda)=-\frac{1}{x^\star+y^\star}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x^\star,y^\star,\Lambda)=\frac{1}{x^\star+y^\star}$. I was trying to take it from there for the second derivative but to no avail. Numerically, I find that $\frac{\partial x^\star}{\partial \Lambda}>0$ and  $\frac{\partial y^\star}{\partial \Lambda}<0$ which would be enough to prove the result...

Comment: Oh yeah, I did have that result. Duh. But I didn't see that it got me anywhere. How are you doing anything numerical? I am tempted to look for counterexamples, but haven't yet.

Comment: I do have an explicit form for $f$ in the background:
$$f\left(x,y,\Lambda\right)=\frac{\log (\Lambda +\xi )-\log \left(\frac{\Lambda }{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\Lambda ^2-\frac{4 (x-y)}{\zeta }}\right)}{\log (\Lambda +\xi )-\log (\Lambda -\xi )}$$ with $\Lambda>\xi>\frac{\Lambda}{2}$ and $\zeta>0$.